# How to return weather data from background thread?

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I have this method called getWeatherData which retrieves some weather info from setLabels, another method. I know this is running on the background thread. The four variables I want, city1Info, country1Info, summary1Info and temperature1Info all return nil, so how can I return them on the main thread before this happens?

```
func getWeatherData(lat: Double, long: Double) -> (city1: String, country1: String, summary1: String, temperature1: String) {

    var city1Info = ""
    var country1Info = ""
    var summary1Info = ""
    var temperature1Info = ""

    let url = NSURL(string: "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.placefinder%20where%20text%3D%22\(lat)%2C\(long)%22%20and%20gflags%3D%22R%22)&format=json")

    // Task does not get onto the main thread until weather data has been retrieved. 
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) { (data, response, error) in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.setLabels(data!)
            city1Info = self.setLabels(data!).city
            country1Info = self.setLabels(data!).country
            summary1Info = self.setLabels(data!).summary
            temperature1Info = self.setLabels(data!).temperature

        })
    }

    task.resume()
    return(city1Info, country1Info, summary1Info, temperature1Info)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the same way you are retrieving the data asynchronously you have to make the `getWeatherData` function asynchronous. You can send to this function a block that will be invoked with the result.

```
func getWeatherData(lat: Double, long: Double, completion: (city1: String, country1: String, summary1: String, temperature1: String) -> Void) {   
    let url = NSURL(string: "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.placefinder%20where%20text%3D%22\(lat)%2C\(long)%22%20and%20gflags%3D%22R%22)&format=json")

    // Task does not get onto the main thread until weather data has been retrieved. 
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) { (data, response, error) in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            //Get information from data
            let city1Info = ...
            let country1Info = ...
            let summary1Info = ...
            let temperature1Info = ...

            completion(city1Info, country1Info, summary1Info, temperature1Info)
        })
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, this has worked perfectly and the app is now finished!

Comment: No problem buddy, we are here to help. I'd very happy if you could please accept the answer.